# Regex creation for JS validation

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm having some trouble creating the proper regex to validate input.  I feel it is pretty simple to do but am still having a couple issues.

the ideal input would be as follows without the quotes: "tests.xxxxxxx" with the x's being replaced with any alphanumeric character.  the only non-alphanumeric character is the period that separates 'tests' from the second half of the string.

```
(tests\.){1}
```

Comment: Are you just trying to validate that the string is like `"test.12jhg"`? If so, then `/tests\.\w+$/.test(string)` should do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following regex with `test()` to validate:

```
tests\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+
```

**Edit:** If you want to restrict only one `tests` you can use a lookahead:

```
tests\.(?!.*tests)[a-zA-Z0-9]+
```

Comment: is there any way to limit it to allow only one copy of 'tests.'  as it is right now, I can enter tests.tests.whatever.